# Generating and applying gradient to svg shape with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to add a gradient of different colors (meant to symbolize the percentage of different answers recorded in a survey) to a svg shape (in this case, the shape is a country the user has clicked on). [I want it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQZ65.jpg) (please ignore the awful choice of colors).

However, this screenshot is taken when the percentage data for each answer is hard coded (visible to the right in the picture), and not fetched from the csv file with the survey data. So, I wrote this snippet of code to generate a gradient based on the data in the survey. It calculates the percentage each answer received, and creates two offset-attributes that defines the boundaries for that specific answer (which is then applied to the gradient svg). Finally, this gradient is applied to the country the user clicked on.

```
function calculateGrad(csvData, noOfQuestions, chosenCountry){
    var total = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfQuestions; i++) {
        total += parseInt(csvData[i][chosenCountry])
    }

    var grad = svg.append("defs")
        .append("linearGradient")
        .attr("id", "grad")
        .attr("x1", "0%")
        .attr("x2", "0%")
        .attr("y1", "100%")
        .attr("y2", "0%")


    totalPercentFilled = 0
    counter = 0

    for (var i = 0; i < noOfQuestions; i++) {
        var randomColor = "#000000".replace(/0/g,function(){return (~~(Math.random()*16)).toString(16);});
        if (i == 0) {
            grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "0%").attr("stop-color", randomColor)
            var prevColor = randomColor
            counter += 1
        }

        else {
            grad.append("stop").attr("offset", totalPercentFilled).attr("stop-color", randomColor)
            var prevColor = randomColor
            counter += 1
        }
        grad.append("stop").attr("offset", (totalPercentFilled + (parseInt(csvData[i][chosenCountry])/parseInt(total))*100)).attr("stop-color", prevColor);

        totalPercentFilled += (parseInt(csvData[i][chosenCountry])/parseInt(total)*100)
    }

    console.log(grad)
    // console.log("Number of loops made: " + counter)
    // console.log("Number of Q:s: " + noOfQuestions)
    g.selectAll("#" + country.id).style("fill", "url(#grad)")
    console.log("Gradient applied")
```

While this code seems to generate the exact same gradient (to me), [it results in the country getting filled with just one color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax7bs.jpg) (the first of the gradient).

I can't figure out why this happens, as the gradients logged in the console in both examples look identical to me. If someone knows what the problem is I'll be eternally grateful for some guidance.

Please also let me know if I need to provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example D3 screenshot you can see that you are not appending the percentage `%` unit to the gradient `stop`. The default unit for gradient stops is the `objectBoundingBox`, and the units run from 0 to 1.

So your gradient is probably there, it's just `100×` from what you intended. You're only seeing one band of your (very large) gradient.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. Took away the multiplication of 100 in both places and that solved it. I took for granted that I had to do that to apply the percentage values. Thanks again for clearing that up. Works flawlessly now it seems like!